# How to change file output node's file subpath value in python

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, depth-map

I want to change the value of `File Subpath` of `File Output` node in `Compositor` from python. I'm able to change its `basepath`, but I'm unable to change the `File Subpath`. Is it possible to change this from python? If yes, how?

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/output-file-name-beginner-2-82/1204279/5) and it works

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:
    if node.type == 'OUTPUT_FILE':
        node.file_slots[0].path = ''
```

Comment: How did you find out? I also had this problem and thanks to this solved it. Just now still the problem exists with the frame number being appended Image0001.png. How do you disable frame number? I can't find the option to disable this so I opened a new question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272410/python-how-to-change-compositors-file-output-nodes-image-name-without-frame-n

Comment: nevermind! i found out `write_still=True` passed to the `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`