# Python - 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'file'

Tags: python

I can type:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Output Node"].file_slots[0].path == mypath
```

but i can't type:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.file
```

I want to use it my loop, that renaming all file slots in all compositor nodes that contains "Output" string in name

```
for i in bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes:
    if 'Output' in i.name:
            i.file.slots[0].path = mypath

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.blend\Script.py", line x, in <module>
AttributeError: 'CompositorNodeOutputFile' object has no attribute 'file'
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218020/how-to-change-file-output-nodes-file-subpath-value-in-python related

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. We'll call this a duplicate. Of  course , you can still edit to re-open, if you need to.